# How to cut mesh by curved surface

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I need the "extra" from the roof to be removed. For some reason I can't make this work with booleans. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: The Boolean modifier depends on the volume.

Comment: A blend file would be highly useful here, and a better description of exactly what final result you want to achieve.

Comment: @brasshat I think the OP wants to remove the part of the cube above the curved plane. It is possible to make boolean modifiers work without a manifold mesh, if the normals are pointing the right way and you don't have any non-manifold parts intersecting the target object.

Comment: It may be that a booleans modifier is the best way to go, but I'm not yet convinced of that, partly because I personally lack the information to make that judgement. The boolean modifier may be better now; when I explored it several versions back, I found it tended to produce geometry which needed so much cleanup in a situation similar to the one illustrated by the OP, that it was easier to modify the geometry in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me exactly what you mean by '"extra" from the roof'. If you mean the overhang on the sides, you could modify the geometry by cutting (in any one of several ways, though in my own workflow a boolean modifier would not be a choice I'd make) the surface of the roof, and removing the vertices outside the new geometry.

If instead of that, you mean the parts of the rectangles extending above the roof, then you'd probably want to modify the walls. Again, there are several ways to accomplish this, but exactly which one would be most useful is hard to say without seeing more information.